# How can I make in a responsive way dat a column of pictures have the same height dat the column of text

Tags: html, css

I'm just an student and I'm making a website for a Music Band for my Eind Project.

In my layout, in the page "Events," I made two columns; one column with the information of the Events (5 divs), and in the other column just a photo gallery with background-images (4 divs).

My problem is that I don't know how to make the heights from the two columns responsive, and at the same time that the heights of the two columns remain equal.

I can make it right in 100% screen, but if the screen gets smaller my column text becomes larger, but my pictures much smaller:

[100% screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xx4AE.png):

[image]

[800px screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFdYW.png)

[image]

How can I solve this problem? I tried to fix the column with the gallery with flex, grid, max-with, min-with,  percentages, calc() to fix the height of the pictures but still I'm not doing this right.

Do I have to change also the column of the text? Do I need JavaScript for this?

```css
.section_RawhideEvents{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    padding-bottom: 14rem;

}
.section_RawhideEvents h2{
    padding-left: 1rem;
}


@media (min-width: 770px) { 
.section_RawhideEvents h2{
    padding: 6rem 16%;
}}
@media (min-width: 770px) { 
.RawhideEvents{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
}}
.events_links{
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: center;
gap: 6rem;
padding-top: 5%;

}
@media (min-width: 770px) { 
.events_links{
    width: 60%;  
     

}}

.events_rechts_fotogallery{
.events_rechts_fotogallery {
    display: none;
    padding-top: 5%;
}
@media (min-width: 770px) {
    .events_rechts_fotogallery {
        width: 40%;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        gap: 2rem;
    }
}

.events_rechts_fotogallery_img1 {
    background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/450/395);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    width: 40%;
    aspect-ratio: 1;
}
.events_rechts_fotogallery_img2 {
    background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/450/395);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    width: 40%;
    aspect-ratio: 1;
}
.events_rechts_fotogallery_img3 {
    background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/450/395);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    width: 40%;
    aspect-ratio: 1;
}
.events_rechts_fotogallery_img4 {
    background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/450/395);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    width: 40%;
    aspect-ratio: 1;
}
.rawhide_events_block{
    
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    gap: 10%;
    width: 70%;
    
}
.event_block_info .event{
    width: 100%;
}

.rawhide_date_event{
    border: solid 0.4rem var(--or
    width:fit-content;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1rem 3rem;
 }
 .rawhide_date_event p{
    color: var(--orange);
 }

.event_block_info .event h5{
    font-weight:500;
    color:#f39863 ;
    padding-left: 0;
}
.event_adres{
    display: flex;
    gap: 2rem;
    align-items: center;
    
}
.event_adres svg{
    width: 3rem;
}
.event_date{
    padding-bottom: 2rem;
}
.event_link button{
    width: 25rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="RawhideEvents">
       <div class="events_links"> 
        <!--  EVENT 1  -->
        <div class="rawhide_events_block event1"> 
        <div class=" rawhide_date_event">
        <p>june <br><span> 09</span><br><span>2023 </span></p>
        </div>
        <div class="event_block_info">
         <div class="event">
         <h5>Zaal Kaleidoscoop </h5>
<div class="event_legend">Rawhide in full concert with 
very special guest. </div>
         </div>
         <div class="event_adres">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" 
height="26" viewBox="0 0 16 26">
     <g id="Group_74" data-name="Group 74" 
transform="translate(-0.401 0.318)">
         <g id="Union_1" data-name="Union 1" 
transform="translate(0.401 -0.318)"
             fill="#d73802">
             <path
                 d="M 7.99998950958252 24.85818862915039 L 
1.501270055770874 11.51653003692627 L 1.
493070006370544 11.49969959259033 L 1.
48363995552063 11.48353004455566 C 0.
8401399850845337 10.38051986694336 0.5 9.
122190475463867 0.5 7.844580173492432 C 0.
5 3.79475998878479 3.864490032196045 0.5 
8 0.5 C 12.13551044464111 0.5 15.5 3.
79475998878479 15.5 7.844580173492432 C 
15.5 9.123049736022949 15.15939998626709 
10.38199996948242 14.5150203704834 11.
48534965515137 L 14.50551986694336 11.
50162029266357 L 14.49726963043213 11.
51856994628906 L 7.99998950958252 24.
85818862915039 Z"
                 stroke="none" />
             <path
                 d="M 8 1 C 4.140190124511719 1 1 4.
070470809936523 1 7.844579696655273 C 1 9.
03373908996582 1.316579818725586 10.
2049503326416 1.915510177612305 11.
23157978057861 L 1.934379577636719 11.
26391983032227 L 7.999969482421875 23.
71636772155762 L 14.06424999237061 11.
26574039459229 L 14.08325958251953 11.
23320007324219 C 14.68299961090088 10.
20629024505615 15 9.034519195556641 15 7.
844579696655273 C 15 4.070470809936523 11.
85980987548828 1 8 1 M 8 0 C 12.
41845989227295 0 16 3.5118408203125 16 7.
844579696655273 C 16 9.261240005493164 15.
61670017242432 10.59043025970459 14.
94678020477295 11.73750972747803 L 8 26 L 
1.051759719848633 11.73548984527588 C 0.
3828096389770508 10.5888500213623 0 9.
26045036315918 0 7.844579696655273 C 0 3.
5118408203125 3.582030296325684 0 8 0 Z"
                 stroke="none" fill="#fbede0" />
         </g>
         <g id="Ellipse_2" data-name="Ellipse 2" 
transform="translate(3.401 2.682)"
             fill="#d73802" stroke="#fbede0" 
stroke-width="1">
             <circle cx="5" cy="5" r="5" stroke="none" />
             <circle cx="5" cy="5" r="4.5" fill="none" />
         </g>
     </g>
 </svg>
 <p>Molenstraat 50, 2640 Mortsel, BE
 </p>
         </div>
          <div class="event_date">Fri. 09 Jun @ 20:15</div><a 
class="link_rawhide_event" href="Rawhide.Home.html">more 
info</a>
          <div class="event_link"> </div>
          </div>
          </div>
          <!--  EVENT 2  -->
          <div class="rawhide_events_block event2">
           <div class=" rawhide_date_event">
     <p>june <br><span></span> 28</span><br><span>2023 <span></p>
 </div>
 <div class="event_block_info">
     <div class="event">
         <h5>Private Party</h5>
         <div class="event_legend">Access to this party is 
restricted to invited guests only.
         </div>
     </div>
     <div class="event_adres">
         <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" 
height="26" viewBox="0 0 16 26">
             <g id="Group_74" data-name="Group 74" 
transform="translate(-0.401 0.318)">
                 <g id="Union_1" data-name="Union 1" 
transform="translate(0.401 -0.318)"
                     fill="#d73802">
                     <path
                         d="M 7.99998950958252 24.85818862915039 L 
1.501270055770874 11.51653003692627 L 1.
493070006370544 11.49969959259033 L 1.
48363995552063 11.48353004455566 C 0.
8401399850845337 10.38051986694336 0.5 9.
122190475463867 0.5 7.844580173492432 C 0.
5 3.79475998878479 3.864490032196045 0.5 
8 0.5 C 12.13551044464111 0.5 15.5 3.
79475998878479 15.5 7.844580173492432 C 
15.5 9.123049736022949 15.15939998626709 
10.38199996948242 14.5150203704834 11.
48534965515137 L 14.50551986694336 11.
50162029266357 L 14.49726963043213 11.
51856994628906 L 7.99998950958252 24.
85818862915039 Z"
                         stroke="none" />
                     <path
                         d="M 8 1 C 4.140190124511719 1 1 4.
070470809936523 1 7.844579696655273 C 1 9.
03373908996582 1.316579818725586 10.
2049503326416 1.915510177612305 11.
23157978057861 L 1.934379577636719 11.
26391983032227 L 7.999969482421875 23.
71636772155762 L 14.06424999237061 11.
26574039459229 L 14.08325958251953 11.
23320007324219 C 14.68299961090088 10.
20629024505615 15 9.034519195556641 15 7.
844579696655273 C 15 4.070470809936523 11.
85980987548828 1 8 1 M 8 0 C 12.
41845989227295 0 16 3.5118408203125 16 7.
844579696655273 C 16 9.261240005493164 15.
61670017242432 10.59043025970459 14.
94678020477295 11.73750972747803 L 8 26 L 
1.051759719848633 11.73548984527588 C 0.
3828096389770508 10.5888500213623 0 9.
26045036315918 0 7.844579696655273 C 0 3.
5118408203125 3.582030296325684 0 8 0 Z"
                         stroke="none" fill="#fbede0" />
                 </g>
                 <g id="Ellipse_2" data-name="Ellipse 2" 
transform="translate(3.401 2.682)"
                     fill="#d73802" stroke="#fbede0" 
stroke-width="1">
                     <circle cx="5" cy="5" r="5" stroke="none" />
                     <circle cx="5" cy="5" r="4.5" fill="none" />
                 </g>
             </g>
         </svg>
         <p>Berlaar, BE
         </p>
     </div>
     <div class="event_date">Wen. 28 Jun @ </div>
     <!-- link -->
     <div class="event_link"> <a href="#"><button
                 class="button viewEvents" type="button ">
                 more info
             </button></a></div>
 </div>
          </div>
          <!--  EVENT 3  -->
          <div class="rawhide_events_block event3">
           <div class=" rawhide_date_event">
     <p>june <br><span></span> 28</span><br><span>2023 <span></p>
 </div>
 <div class="event_block_info">
     <div class="event">
         <h5>Private Party</h5>
         <div class="event_legend">Access to this party is 
restricted to invited guests only.
         </div>
     </div>
     <div class="event_adres">
         <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" 
height="26" viewBox="0 0 16 26">
             <g id="Group_74" data-name="Group 74" 
transform="translate(-0.401 0.318)">
                 <g id="Union_1" data-name="Union 1" 
transform="translate(0.401 -0.318)"
                     fill="#d73802">
                     <path
                         d="M 7.99998950958252 24.85818862915039 L 
1.501270055770874 11.51653003692627 L 1.
493070006370544 11.49969959259033 L 1.
48363995552063 11.48353004455566 C 0.
8401399850845337 10.38051986694336 0.5 9.
122190475463867 0.5 7.844580173492432 C 0.
5 3.79475998878479 3.864490032196045 0.5 
8 0.5 C 12.13551044464111 0.5 15.5 3.
79475998878479 15.5 7.844580173492432 C 
15.5 9.123049736022949 15.15939998626709 
10.38199996948242 14.5150203704834 11.
48534965515137 L 14.50551986694336 11.
50162029266357 L 14.49726963043213 11.
51856994628906 L 7.99998950958252 24.
85818862915039 Z"
                         stroke="none" />
                     <path
                         d="M 8 1 C 4.140190124511719 1 1 4.
070470809936523 1 7.844579696655273 C 1 9.
03373908996582 1.316579818725586 10.
2049503326416 1.915510177612305 11.
23157978057861 L 1.934379577636719 11.
26391983032227 L 7.999969482421875 23.
71636772155762 L 14.06424999237061 11.
26574039459229 L 14.08325958251953 11.
23320007324219 C 14.68299961090088 10.
20629024505615 15 9.034519195556641 15 7.
844579696655273 C 15 4.070470809936523 11.
85980987548828 1 8 1 M 8 0 C 12.
41845989227295 0 16 3.5118408203125 16 7.
844579696655273 C 16 9.261240005493164 15.
61670017242432 10.59043025970459 14.
94678020477295 11.73750972747803 L 8 26 L 
1.051759719848633 11.73548984527588 C 0.
3828096389770508 10.5888500213623 0 9.
26045036315918 0 7.844579696655273 C 0 3.
5118408203125 3.582030296325684 0 8 0 Z"
                         stroke="none" fill="#fbede0" />
                 </g>
                 <g id="Ellipse_2" data-name="Ellipse 2" 
transform="translate(3.401 2.682)"
                     fill="#d73802" stroke="#fbede0" 
stroke-width="1">
                     <circle cx="5" cy="5" r="5" stroke="none" />
                     <circle cx="5" cy="5" r="4.5" fill="none" />
                 </g>
             </g>
         </svg>
         <p>Berlaar, BE
         </p>
     </div>
     <div class="event_date">Wen. 28 Jun @ </div>
     <!-- link -->
     <div class="event_link"> <a href="#"><button
                 class="button viewEvents" type="button ">
                 more info
             </button></a></div>
 </div>
          </div>
          <!--  EVENT 4  -->
          <div class="rawhide_events_block event4">
           <div class=" rawhide_date_event">
     <p>june <br><span></span> 28</span><br><span>2023 <span></p>
 </div>
 <div class="event_block_info">
     <div class="event">
         <h5>Private Party</h5>
         <div class="event_legend">Access to this party is 
restricted to invited guests only.
         </div>
     </div>
     <div class="event_adres">
         <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" 
height="26" viewBox="0 0 16 26">
             <g id="Group_74" data-name="Group 74" 
transform="translate(-0.401 0.318)">
                 <g id="Union_1" data-name="Union 1" 
transform="translate(0.401 -0.318)"
                     fill="#d73802">
                     <path
                         d="M 7.99998950958252 24.85818862915039 L 
1.501270055770874 11.51653003692627 L 1.
493070006370544 11.49969959259033 L 1.
48363995552063 11.48353004455566 C 0.
8401399850845337 10.38051986694336 0.5 9.
122190475463867 0.5 7.844580173492432 C 0.
5 3.79475998878479 3.864490032196045 0.5 
8 0.5 C 12.13551044464111 0.5 15.5 3.
79475998878479 15.5 7.844580173492432 C 
15.5 9.123049736022949 15.15939998626709 
10.38199996948242 14.5150203704834 11.
48534965515137 L 14.50551986694336 11.
50162029266357 L 14.49726963043213 11.
51856994628906 L 7.99998950958252 24.
85818862915039 Z"
                         stroke="none" />
                     <path
                         d="M 8 1 C 4.140190124511719 1 1 4.
070470809936523 1 7.844579696655273 C 1 9.
03373908996582 1.316579818725586 10.
2049503326416 1.915510177612305 11.
23157978057861 L 1.934379577636719 11.
26391983032227 L 7.999969482421875 23.
71636772155762 L 14.06424999237061 11.
26574039459229 L 14.08325958251953 11.
23320007324219 C 14.68299961090088 10.
20629024505615 15 9.034519195556641 15 7.
844579696655273 C 15 4.070470809936523 11.
85980987548828 1 8 1 M 8 0 C 12.
41845989227295 0 16 3.5118408203125 16 7.
844579696655273 C 16 9.261240005493164 15.
61670017242432 10.59043025970459 14.
94678020477295 11.73750972747803 L 8 26 L 
1.051759719848633 11.73548984527588 C 0.
3828096389770508 10.5888500213623 0 9.
26045036315918 0 7.844579696655273 C 0 3.
5118408203125 3.582030296325684 0 8 0 Z"
                         stroke="none" fill="#fbede0" />
                 </g>
                 <g id="Ellipse_2" data-name="Ellipse 2" 
transform="translate(3.401 2.682)"
                     fill="#d73802" stroke="#fbede0" 
stroke-width="1">
                     <circle cx="5" cy="5" r="5" stroke="none" />
                     <circle cx="5" cy="5" r="4.5" fill="none" />
                 </g>
             </g>
         </svg>
         <p>Berlaar, BE
         </p>
     </div>
     <div class="event_date">Wen. 28 Jun @ </div>
     <!-- link -->
     <div class="event_link"> <a href="#"><button
                 class="button viewEvents" type="button ">
                 more info
             </button></a></div>
 </div>
          </div>
          <!--  EVENT 5  -->
          <div class="rawhide_events_block event5">
           <div class=" rawhide_date_event">
     <p>june <br><span></span> 28</span><br><span>2023 <span></p>
 </div>
 <div class="event_block_info">
     <div class="event">
         <h5>Private Party</h5>
         <div class="event_legend">Access to this party is 
restricted to invited guests only.
         </div>
     </div>
     <div class="event_adres">
         <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" 
height="26" viewBox="0 0 16 26">
             <g id="Group_74" data-name="Group 74" 
transform="translate(-0.401 0.318)">
                 <g id="Union_1" data-name="Union 1" 
transform="translate(0.401 -0.318)"
                     fill="#d73802">
                     <path
                         d="M 7.99998950958252 24.85818862915039 L 
1.501270055770874 11.51653003692627 L 1.
493070006370544 11.49969959259033 L 1.
48363995552063 11.48353004455566 C 0.
8401399850845337 10.38051986694336 0.5 9.
122190475463867 0.5 7.844580173492432 C 0.
5 3.79475998878479 3.864490032196045 0.5 
8 0.5 C 12.13551044464111 0.5 15.5 3.
79475998878479 15.5 7.844580173492432 C 
15.5 9.123049736022949 15.15939998626709 
10.38199996948242 14.5150203704834 11.
48534965515137 L 14.50551986694336 11.
50162029266357 L 14.49726963043213 11.
51856994628906 L 7.99998950958252 24.
85818862915039 Z"
                         stroke="none" />
                     <path
                         d="M 8 1 C 4.140190124511719 1 1 4.
070470809936523 1 7.844579696655273 C 1 9.
03373908996582 1.316579818725586 10.
2049503326416 1.915510177612305 11.
23157978057861 L 1.934379577636719 11.
26391983032227 L 7.999969482421875 23.
71636772155762 L 14.06424999237061 11.
26574039459229 L 14.08325958251953 11.
23320007324219 C 14.68299961090088 10.
20629024505615 15 9.034519195556641 15 7.
844579696655273 C 15 4.070470809936523 11.
85980987548828 1 8 1 M 8 0 C 12.
41845989227295 0 16 3.5118408203125 16 7.
844579696655273 C 16 9.261240005493164 15.
61670017242432 10.59043025970459 14.
94678020477295 11.73750972747803 L 8 26 L 
1.051759719848633 11.73548984527588 C 0.
3828096389770508 10.5888500213623 0 9.
26045036315918 0 7.844579696655273 C 0 3.
5118408203125 3.582030296325684 0 8 0 Z"
                         stroke="none" fill="#fbede0" />
                 </g>
                 <g id="Ellipse_2" data-name="Ellipse 2" 
transform="translate(3.401 2.682)"
                     fill="#d73802" stroke="#fbede0" 
stroke-width="1">
                     <circle cx="5" cy="5" r="5" stroke="none" />
                     <circle cx="5" cy="5" r="4.5" fill="none" />
                 </g>
             </g>
         </svg>
         <p>Berlaar, BE
         </p>
     </div>
     <div class="event_date">Wen. 28 Jun @ </div>
     <!-- link -->
     <div class="event_link"> <a href="#"><button
                 class="button viewEvents" type="button ">
                 more info
             </button></a></div>
 </div>
          </div>
          </div> 
          <!--  einde  event_links -->
          <!--  fotogallery  -->
          <div class="events_rechts_fotogallery">
          <div class="events_rechts_fotogallery_img1 event_img1"  ></div>
          <div class="events_rechts_fotogallery_img2 event_img2"></div>
          <div class="events_rechts_fotogallery_img3 event_img3" ></div>
          <div class="events_rechts_fotogallery_img4 event_img4"></div>
            </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Could you please share minimal example (codesandbox, stackblitz...) for your issue?

Comment: I added the HTML part, does it help?

Comment: Yes ofc, It will help

Comment: I think your page logic is a bit off. You should have a a main flex column container with flexbox rows of *events*. Each *event row* should be made up of *date*, *info* and *foto*, repeat for all events. *date* and *info* can be flexbox column containers. Going the way you do will get you in layout/responsiveness trouble and positioning of elements.

Comment: @Marina: please note that I've converted your posted HTML and CSS into a running snippet so we can see your code running in the question; I have not however corrected the typos you appear to have left in (`<p>june <br><span></span> 09</span><br><span>2023 </span></p>` is missing an opening `<span>` before the `09`; also `<a class="link_rawhide_event" href="Rawhide.` has an unclosed `href` attribute, within an unclosed `<a>` tag). Please edit and fix these errors.

Comment: Further to the above, could you please add enough content (working demo `<img>` links, and some text) so that your code reproduces something like your pictured layout.

Comment: @Rene: Thank you for your answer  I think I understand what you mean, but the foto's are not from the Events. They are just decoration to the page.  In my design I wanted to break with uniformity. But you are right, it gives in layout/responsiveness trouble and positioning of elements.

Comment: @David Thomas: I added more code but I didn't get de result.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making them a part of a table?

Implemented something like this:

```
<div class="RawhideEvents">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="event_links">
          ...
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="events_rechts_fotogallery">
           ...
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I thought about it, but I didn't learn at school and I was not sure to use or not

Comment: Hi, I will try to use the table for the text, but still I have the problem with the 2nd column. Is it a solution  that I use 'grid area' in both columns + media querie?